# XElement.Parse() - Preserve \r\n in CData

Tags: c#, xml-parsing, xelement

Consider the following piece of code:

```
       string xml = "<test><![CDATA[bla\r\nbla]]></test>";
        var xTest = XElement.Parse(xml, LoadOptions.PreserveWhitespace);
        var value = xTest.Value;
```

The variable 'value' contains the string "bla\nbla", while you would expect "bla\r\nblabla" (especially because it's in a CDATA section).
Is there a way to read the string in the CData tag, preserving the \r\n?

Comment: Is it an option to use `&#10;` instead of `\r`? Note that compliant XML parsers will have to convert `\r\n` to `\n`: https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-line-ends